# Using moment to manipulate date and time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I get the previous day using `moment` as follows:

```
var start_time = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY/MM/DD-00:00:00');
```

This outputs the following:

```
2015/01/29-00:00:00
```

Now I want to the following using `start_time`:

```
2015/01/29-01:00:00
2015/01/29-02:00:00
2015/01/29-03:00:00
2015/01/29-04:00:00
2015/01/29-05:00:00
```

I tried doing it the following way:

```
for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
    console.log(moment(start_time,"YYYY/MM/DD-HH:mm:ss").add(1,'hour'));
}
```

But this is not working. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it.

```
for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){ //make sure to actually use i!
    console.log( //expects a string
        moment(start_time,"YYYY/MM/DD-HH:mm:ss") //this works
        .add(1,'hour') //this will return a moment object, not a string
    );
}
```

So just change it to

```
for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
    console.log(
        moment(start_time,"YYYY/MM/DD-HH:mm:ss")
        .add(i,'hour') //changed to i
        .format('YYYY/MM/DD-HH:mm:ss') //make it a string
    );
}
// Prints
// 2015/01/29-00:00:00
// 2015/01/29-01:00:00
// 2015/01/29-02:00:00
// 2015/01/29-03:00:00
// 2015/01/29-04:00:00
// 2015/01/29-05:00:00
```